# Angular unknown provider when trying to get a constant from another module

Tags: angularjs

Just started on AngularJS, and it has been a challenging ordeal so far.

My problem today is I'm trying to configure a controller through a variable on the URL. I don't want the "real" controller to have to know where a given parameter came from, so long as it's there. The main app controller is therefore responsible of getting the parameter from the URL, and setting a constant that the "real" controller will use.

For the life of me, I cannot see what I am doing wrong in the initialization. Any help would be greatly appreciated (including what are standard practices to troubleshoot these kind of issues :))

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <!-- the base tag is required for th Angular.js $location.search() function to work correctly -->
    <base href='/' />
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("myController.constants", []);
        angular.module("myApp", ["myController", "myController.constants"], function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        })
        .controller("myAppCtrl", ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
            var searchObject = $location.search();
            angular.module("myController.constants").constant('myConstant', searchObject['theConstant']);
        }]);
     </script>
    <script src="js/controllerExample.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="myControllerCtrl">
        <p>The constant is {{theConstant}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js for the controller:

```
angular.module("myController", ["myController.constants"])
.controller("myControllerCtrl", ['$scope', 'myConstant', function ($scope, myConstant) {
    $scope.theConstant = myConstant;
}]);
```

With the code above, I keep getting this error message

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myConstantProvider <- myConstant <- myControllerCtrl

Thanks!

Comment: I could be mistaken but I don't think you can declare a module inside a controller declaration.

Comment: myConstant doesn't exist. You need to have a factory/service/value created with that name before you can inject it somewhere.

Comment: Controllers defining constants for other controllers is probably not such a good idea.  At the very least you will to make it a value.  But like @Komo said, it don't know if defining things like this will make it into the di injector.  Best to use a service for these sorts of communication.

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken but I don't think you can declare a module inside a controller declaration. Try putting

```
angular.module("myController.constants").constant('myConstant', searchObject['theConstant']);
```

outside "myAppCtrl" declaration.

Comment: That's it. The reason is that the controller code runs _after_ the dependency injector tries to locate `myConstant`. You are defining it, but too late.

Comment: It is the reason for the errors but it won't really solve the problem since the op wants info based on the current location.  Hopefully, he will soon discover the router and realize it's not so bad.